# Make toggleable content take up remaining height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an amount of columns and when each column is clicked, the content for that column is shown below. How can I make the toggleable content take up remaining height when it's visible so that the layout will be responsive? Is it possible with css only or do I need to use js as well?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.column').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.content').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 20%;
}

.column.active {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.toggle {
  width: 25%;
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="toggle">1</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="toggle">2</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>content 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="toggle">3</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>content 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdornell/r0jkyjLo/24/) of what I've done so far.

Comment: What do you mean by 'remaining height'? The content divs will expand to fit the size of their content.

Comment: if you set `.column.active {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}`, then you want to set `height: 100px;` for `.content`?

Comment: I mean the height between each row with columns.

Comment: @Banzay Yes, but I want the height to be in percentage so that it adjust to screen width.

Answer (score 0):

if im understanding you correctly. u want to create a sort of accordeon. if u have 4 tabs. and open one it displays some text. and if u click another one it wil open that one, close the one before and remain in its heigt.

u need javascript or jsfiddle or something like that for this to work perfectly.

so if this was your problem. google something like: "how to make an accordeon menu".
There may be ways to do this pure css but im not sure about it.

sorry if it wasnt your problem

Comment: Yes, I've done that but all of the examples is with full width menu and not like a column or grid-like menu. I know how to do an accordion with content beneath but my problem is to handle the columns and position of the toggable content.

Comment: well. if u use bootstrap, becouse most tutorials are based uppon this when it comes to the accordeon thing. put it in a div or row and devine how large it can be. or set fixed height width for the dropdown content.

Comment: try setting your position tag of the content box to  position: relative;

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.column').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.content').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 20%;
}

.column.active {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.toggle {
  width: 25%;
  height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="toggle">1</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="toggle">2</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>content 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="toggle">3</div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>content 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can click on the full page button to test it's responsibility

Comment: Kind of but not exactly. If I add more columns on a new row I want the expanded content to push down the next row. So the expanded content should be as high as it needs to be and the next row should always be right below the expanded content.

Answer (score 0):

- To get the available space subtract the height of the window ($(window).height ()) from offset of the column + height of the column.
- Set margin-bottom of active column = to available space (availSpace) to push second row of columns down.

**EDIT:**
If you don't want ".content" to fill the viewport just remove the var(availSpace) to find available space, then set height of the ".content" (myContent.height) to margin-bottom of the column

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.column').on('click', function(){
     $("#wrapper").find (".column").css ({"margin-bottom": 0});
        $("#wrapper").find (".content").css ({"display": "none"});
      
      var myContent = $(this).find('.content');
      // var availSpace = $(window).height () - ($(this).offset ().top + $(this).height ());
      
     myContent.addClass('active');
      myContent.css ({"display": "inline-block"});
      $(this).css ({"margin-bottom": myContent.height ()});
   });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
}

.content {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%; 
    color: #000;
    left: 0; 
    top: auto; 
    display: none; 
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.column {
    display: inline-block; 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
    width: 20%; 
}


            
.toggle {
   width: 25%;
   height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="toggle">1</div>
        <div class="content">     
          <p>content 1</p>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="column">
        <div class="toggle">2</div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content 2<br>
            content 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="toggle">3</div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="toggle">4</div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content 4</p>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="column">
        <div class="toggle">5</div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content 5</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="toggle">6</div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content 6</p>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="column">
        <div class="toggle">7</div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>content 7</p>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: That's close to what I want but I only want the height take up as much space as needed for the content box. So the height should not be the same as window but the same as the content class. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @jdo I have updated the code. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Almost but now the content gets on top of the underlaying columns if you resize the window. They should always be at the bottom of the content box.

Comment: Let's continue this in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136365/question-42389112